# PHP filter_var issue

Tags: php

I have:

```
$user_number = trim(preg_replace( "/\s+/", " ", $_POST['number']));
```

And so:

```
if(!filter_var($user_number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
{
    echo "<script>alert('Invalid number inserted.');</script>";
}
```

The problem is that this code accepts negative numbers like -70, -20, -30! Why?

Comment: what is your desired output ? Please mention over there.

Comment: I just want accept natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer can be negative. If you want to restrict the range the value can have, you can add options to the validate filter:

```
$options = [
    'options' => [
        'min_range' => 0,
        'max_range' => 1000    // or for example PHP_INT_MAX
    ]
];

if (!filter_var($user_number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have check a separate condition to check the negative value please look into my code:

```
$user_number = trim(preg_replace( "/\s+/", " ", $_POST['number']));

if($user_number < 0 || !filter_var($user_number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
{
    echo "<script>alert('Invalid number inserted.');</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution might be help you. Add one additional condition

```
$user_number = trim(preg_replace( "/\s+/", " ", $_POST['number']));

if(!filter_var($user_number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) || (!ereg('^[0-9]+$', $user_number)))
{
    echo "<script>alert('Invalid number inserted.');</script>";
}
```